# Why is the console.log and functions inside this controller not working?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

The `console.log` statement isn't logging anything, and neither is the rest of the code inside my controller function:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp.manage.alertDirectives', [])
.directive('alert-bar', function () {

    return {
        template: 
            '<section ng-show="showAlert" ' +
            'ng-click="closeNotification()" ' +
            'class="ng-notification"> ' +
            '<p class="alert-msg">{{alert_message}}</p> ' +
            '<div class="alert-bg {{alert_type}}"></div> ' +
            '</section>',
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function($scope,
                             ScopeFactory) {

            console.log('inside controller for alerts Directive:');
            var vs = $scope;
            ScopeFactory.saveScope('alerts', vs);
        }
    };
});
```

However in my other directive's controller, the code there is working!

```
var app = angular.module('myApp.manage.termsDirectives', 
['myApp.manage.alertDirectives'])

.directive('termsForm', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: "manage/terms/termsForm.html",
        restrict: "E",
        controller: function($scope,
                             $location,
                             ApiFactory,
                             TermsFactory,
                             TermsStringFactory,
                             ScopeFactory) {

            console.log('inside controller for termsForm Directive:');
```

`<alert-bar></alert-bar>` is at the top of my page, and `<terms-form></terms-form>` is inside of another controller:

`<div class="container" ng-view></div>` contains the following:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 terms-container" ng-controller="TermsCtrl as tc">
    <div class="row" id="term-form-block">
        <terms-form></terms-form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<alert-bar>`'s directive normalized name should be camel-cased:

```
.directive("alertBar", function(){...})
```

when registering a directive - just like it is for `"termsForm"`.